# How do I fix the error message: Event validation is enabled; arguments originate from the server control that originally rendered them

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a problem with two checkBoxes!

```
private CheckBox rdYes;
private CheckBox rdNo;

            rdYes = new CheckBox();
            rdYes.Text = "Yes";
            rdYes.Checked = false;
            rdNo = new CheckBox();
            rdNo.Text = "No";
            rdNo.Checked = false;
```

Error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation

I instantiating the checkboxes in :

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
            this.Controls.Add(rdYes);
            this.Controls.Add(rdNo);
     }
```

And I need to check one CheckBox.

[image]

Comment: Where are you actually instantiating the checkboxes?

Comment: I have exam with CheckBox, because radioButton have AutoPostBack and to check only one, the page is refreshing...

Comment: `CreateChildControls` should also call the base method.

Comment: I need a solution for this problem or not refreshing the page...

Comment: On check of check box , is refreshing right?

Comment: @ГеоргиКръстев please don't put 'solved' in the title. The question is 'solved' when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I need to check only one CheckBox...

If you need to check only one checkbox then you can better try to use `Radio Button`.

However if you want to make sure that only one checkbox is selected then try like this:

```
CheckBox prevChecked;
private void clickCheckBox(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   CheckBox myCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;
   if(myCheckBox != prevChecked && prevChecked!=null) prevChecked.Checked = false;
   {
       prevChecked = myCheckBox.Checked ? myCheckBox : null;
   }
}
```

and if you want that the page should not be refreshed then you can try to set `AutoPostBack="false"` for your Checkbox property.

```
rdYes = new CheckBox();
rdYes.Text = "Yes";
rdYes.Checked = false;
rdYes.AutoPostBack=false;
rdNo = new CheckBox();
rdNo.Text = "No";
rdNo.Checked = false;
rdNo.AutoPostBack=false;
```

Comment: @ГеоргиКръстев:- Did you try to use `AutoPostBack="false"` for your Checkbox property?

Comment: rdYes.AutoPostBack = false; rdNo.AutoPostBack = false; ---> WORKING

Comment: @ГеоргиКръстев:- Great, Happy coding :)

Comment: Problem with choose only one cb ?             rdNo.ValidationGroup = "Valid";
            rdYes.ValidationGroup = "Valid";  OR?

Comment: @ГеоргиКръстев:- As I said initially, you can better create Radio buttons. They will solve your purpose

Comment: @ГеоргиКръстев:- Please check the forum: http://forums.asp.net/t/1517886.aspx?How+to+avoid+page+refresh+on+radiobutton+list+selected+index+changed

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   rdYes = new CheckBox();
   rdYes.ID = "chkYes";
   rdYes.Text = "Yes";
   rdYes.Checked = false;
   rdYes.AutoPostBack=false;
   rdYes.Attributes.Add("onclick","ToggleCheckboxes();return false") 
   rdNo = new CheckBox();
   rdNo.ID = "chkNo";
   rdNo.Text = "No";
   rdNo.Checked = false;
   rdNo.AutoPostBack=false; 
   rdNo.Attributes.Add("onclick","ToggleCheckboxes();return false")
```

Add Javascript function to your page

```
function CheckCheckboxes() {

    if(document.getElementid('<%=chkYes.ClientID%>').checked==true)
    {
       document.getElementid('<%=chkNo.ClientID%>').checked=false;
    }
    else if(document.getElementid('<%=chkNo.ClientID%>').checked==true)
    {
      document.getElementid('<%=chkYes.ClientID%>').checked=false;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you, BEST REGARDS!

Comment: Problem with choose only one cb ?

Comment: two cb in one group or ?

Comment: Why not using radio button??

Comment: You can create Event as well with Radio Buttons

Comment: @ГеоргиКръстев Updated Ans